# Can I convert row headers to repeating row values in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

#### **Edit:** [Google Sheet Example (with Solution implemented)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FXFZaT0TWKjgEGeiOoPUGvq_B2tzCqh2W-uDh6r-V-E/edit?usp=sharing)

---

I have a table that looks like this:

| . | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Email 1** | **Email 2** | **Email 3** | **Email 4** | **Email 5** |
| 2 | ***some@email.com*** | butt@cheeks.com | column@c.com | one@for.com | almost@done.com |
| 3 | another@that.com | fart@face.com | not@d.com | the@money.com | the@end.com |
| 4 | okay@that.com | much@typing.com |  | two@for.com | ***some@email.com*** |
| 5 | all@different.com | boring@example.com |  |  |  |
| 6 | who@cares.com | ***some@email.com*** |  |  |  |
| 7 | tidious@question.com |  |  |  |  |

I need to take the row values and list them as a single column. In the second column, I need the relevant headers to populate as values—like this (disregard bold):

| . | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Email** | **Email ID** |
| 2 | ***some@email.com*** | ***Email 1*** |
| 2 | ***some@email.com*** | ***Email 2*** |
| 2 | ***some@email.com*** | ***Email 5*** |
| 3 | another@that.com | Email 1 |
| 4 | okay@that.com | Email 1 |
| 5 | all@different.com | Email 1 |
| 6 | who@cares.com | Email 1 |
| 7 | tidious@question.com | Email 1 |
| 8 | butt@cheeks.com | Email 2 |
| 9 | fart@face.com | Email 2 |
| 10 | much@typing.com | Email 2 |
| 11 | boring@example.com | Email 2 |
| 12 | column@c.com | Email 3 |
| 13 | not@d.com | Email 3 |
| 14 | one@for.com | Email 4 |
| 15 | the@money.com | Email 4 |
| 16 | two@for.com | Email 4 |
| 17 | almost@done.com | Email 5 |
| 18 | the@end.com | Email 5 |

Comment: Share your sample sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FXFZaT0TWKjgEGeiOoPUGvq_B2tzCqh2W-uDh6r-V-E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`=ArrayFormula({"Email","Email ID";SORT(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(A2:E="",,A2:E&"|"&A1:E1)),"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null"),"|"),1,1,2,1)})`

If you are going to use this in a separate sheet (recommended), just be sure the prepend the name of the source sheet to all ranges in the formula (e.g., Sheet1!A2:E, etc.)

Headers are formed first within the virtual array created between the curly brackets. Comma means "place to the right." Semicolon means "place underneath."

`IF` creates a concatenation for all non-blank cells in A2:E to include the cell value, a pipe symbol and the header for that column.

`FLATTEN` forms one column from all of the newly concatenated strings.

`QUERY` weeds out blank rows in that one-column array.

`SPLIT` splits the results into to columns at the pipe symbol, leaving an email address in column one and its previous header in column two.

`SORT` sorts them A-Z by email address (to group similar) and then by previous email header.